# Ultimate Fix for IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState

Tags: android, android-fragments, illegalstateexception

I was made to understand that this was a bug that plagued the support library versions prior 2015.
But Alas! this is 2016 and `IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState` is still crashing my apps when I call
`.show`, `.commit`,`.dismiss` on  fragments.

I have read this [solution](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/08/fragment-transaction-commit-state-loss.html) and my app will have to constantly fail the third rule **Avoid performing transactions inside asynchronous callback methods** because I must commit or dismiss fragments in Volley's onErrorResponse.

I have tried the following solutions:

1. **Try catching the error**: I tried this with `.show`.

   ```
   try { tagCatFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "TagCAatFragment");
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
   ```

The  problem is that the dialog just shows the first time. After that the dialog refuses to show.

2. **Removing call to `super.onSaveInstanceState`** The state of the fragment refused to be saved.
3. **.dismissAllowingStateLoss(); and .commitAllowingStateLoss();** So far I ave't seen any problem with it. but I cannot use for it `.show` calls.

Please, do you have a better solution?

I was thinking of using FragmentManager instead of supportFragmentManager since my app supports API 16+ but I don't know if this is a very good solution.

Comment: Show code how and where you're showing/dismissing the fragment dialog

Comment: Sir, in Volley's onResponse